# Shorter way to refer to cells multiple times in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I use the following code block to set some initial values.  I've found my self using this construction a lot and I'm wondering if there's something more concise?

```
Sheets(AppTab).Select
Cells(StartingRow, Range("AppTransEffDate").Column).Value = FirstPymtDueDate
Cells(StartingRow, Range("AppTransAmt").Column).Value = RegularPymt
Cells(StartingRow, Range("AppActionCode").Column).Value = SchPymtDueActionCode
Cells(StartingRow, Range("AppDescr").Column).Value = TransDescr
```

If it matters, each of these ranges is one column wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an enumeration to reference the column numbers.  Enumerations go at the top of a code module.  The next enumeration in the list is increment 1 from the previous.  The big advantage of enumerating columns is when you need to reorder your columns; you only have to update your enumeration and your code will run as before. The enumerations also work with intellisense.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum Cols
    cnAppTransEffDate = 2
    cnAppTransAmt = 4
    cnAppActionCode = 5
    cnAppDescr
End Enum


Sub FillData()

    ' Some Code

    With Worksheets(AppTab)
        .Cells(StartingRow, cnAppTransEffDate).Value = FirstPymtDueDate
        .Cells(StartingRow, cnAppTransAmt).Value = RegularPymt
        .Cells(StartingRow, cnAppActionCode).Value = SchPymtDueActionCode
        .Cells(StartingRow, cnAppDescr).Value = TransDescr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've started using this method and the code works but the Intellisense doesn't show the enumerations (but works otherwise).  Is there anything else I need to do to make it pickup the enumerations?  Should it appear after I type: StartingRow, cn[intellisense here]?

Comment: Yes type` cn` and then hold down [ctrl] + [Space Bar].

Answer (score 3):

Use one or more [With ... End With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) statements.

```
with Sheets(AppTab)
    .Cells(StartingRow, .Range("AppTransEffDate").Column) = FirstPymtDueDate
    .Cells(StartingRow, .Range("AppTransAmt").Column) = RegularPymt
    .Cells(StartingRow, .Range("AppActionCode").Column) = SchPymtDueActionCode
    .Cells(StartingRow, .Range("AppDescr").Column) = TransDescr
end with
'alternate
with Sheets(AppTab)
    with .rows(StartingRow)
        .Cells(1, .Range("AppTransEffDate").Column) = FirstPymtDueDate
        .Cells(1, .Range("AppTransAmt").Column) = RegularPymt
        .Cells(1, .Range("AppActionCode").Column) = SchPymtDueActionCode
        .Cells(1, .Range("AppDescr").Column) = TransDescr
    end with
end with
```

I don't think the second With .... End With will show as much improvement as the first in this case but isolating the cells you are referencing is more efficient and avoids repeated calls to locate parentage.

Always referencing the parent worksheet explicitly is widely considered 'best practice' and avoid using .Select and .Activate altogether.

Comment: Is there any way to shorten the 
     .Cells(StartingRow, .Range("AppTransEffDate").Column) = FirstPymtDueDate
(I need to keep StartingRow as a variable because it'll change)

Comment: I have no idea where or what AppTransEffDate, AppTransAmt, AppActionCode and AppDescr refer to so No, I cannot suggest anything.

Comment: Those are ranges.  Each is basically just a long stretch of Col. F, H, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My usual way is to set the first cell of the row range and then to use the `Range._Default` property

```
Set r = Sheets(AppTab).Range("A" & StartingRow)
r(, Range("AppTransEffDate").Column) = FirstPymtDueDate
```

but instead of named ranges, I would use `Enum` like in Thomas Inzina's answer.

If your named ranges start from row 1, then this might work

```
Range("AppTransEffDate")(StartingRow) = FirstPymtDueDate
```

or

```
Set areas = Sheets(AppTab).Range("AppTransEffDate,AppTransAmt,AppActionCode,AppDescr").Areas

areas(1)(StartingRow) = FirstPymtDueDate
areas(2)(StartingRow) = RegularPymt
areas(3)(StartingRow) = SchPymtDueActionCode
areas(4)(StartingRow) = TransDescr
```

or maybe Intersect might work too:

```
Set areas = Sheets(AppTab).Range("(AppTransEffDate,AppTransAmt,AppActionCode,AppDescr) " & StartingRow & ":" & StartingRow).Areas

areas(1) = FirstPymtDueDate
areas(2) = RegularPymt
areas(3) = SchPymtDueActionCode
areas(4) = TransDescr
```